# Proc macro execution order

Tags: rust, macros, rust-proc-macros

I have one `proc macro` that looks like this:

```
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn my_macro(_meta: CompilerTokenStream, input: CompilerTokenStream) -> CompilerTokenStream { //* bits of code */ }
```

Then I have a `derive macro`:

```
#[proc_macro_derive(Operations)]
pub fn operations(input: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> proc_macro::TokenStream { //* bits of code */ }
```

Is it possible to make the derive macro being expanded after the attribute one?

The reason is that I have a crate with some static variables to track data. And I need to read the data in the `derive macro` (the `attribute macro` is the writer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Macros are expanded starting *outside-in* in the syntax tree (because the outermost macro is free to rewrite the inner code so that it has more or fewer macro calls); for attributes this means expansion starts with the topmost attribute first. So, you should get the expansion order you want by writing the attributes in this order:

```rust
#[my_macro]
#[derive(Operations)]
```

---

However, you should not do this at all — you should not use static variables in your macro crate to communicate information. It will work, right now, but the Rust compiler does not promise not to cache macro invocations, run each macro expansion in a separate process/sandbox, or make other such changes to macro expansion that would break your macro's communication path.

(Therefore, the expansion *order* should not matter to you, except that you can know that your macro won't ever see *another macro's expansion* in your own macro's input.)

Comment: You speak specifically about not storing static variables meant to be communicated between macros, but more generally this is a consequence of the "outside-in" expansion order not being guaranteed?

Comment: @bzm3r No, the other way around. The specific thing asked about was the order in which expansions are performed, but because of general principle (macros should be stateless), one shouldn't be relying on that information.